# How to mimic SQL subtraction of results from two different queries in mdx

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I wanted to do the trend analysis between the dates. For an instance current date- 30 days
30-60 days and so on.Below is the snippet of comparable sql query but same I wanted to do in MDX.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
ROUND
(
    (
        (
            (
            SELECT
                SUM(del_pri_impr)
            FROM
                reporting.so_sli_calc_val a,
                reporting.user_group_tenant b,
                reporting.salesorder c
            WHERE
                created_on BETWEEN DATE(now()-30) AND DATE(now())
            )

            -

            (            
            SELECT
                SUM(del_pri_impr)
            FROM
                reporting.so_sli_calc_val a,
                reporting.user_group_tenant b,
                reporting.salesorder c
            WHERE
                created_on BETWEEN DATE(now()-60) AND DATE(now()-30)             
            )
        )

        /

        (
                   SELECT
                       SUM(del_pri_impr)
                   FROM
                       reporting.so_sli_calc_val a,
                       reporting.user_group_tenant b,
                     reporting.salesorder c
                 WHERE
                     created_on BETWEEN DATE(now()-60) AND DATE(now()-30)
        ) *100
    )

,
0
) AS trend
```

**MDX:**

```
WITH
 SET [~FILTER] AS
    {[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-01]:[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-30]}
  SET [~ROWS] AS
  {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
  SELECT
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS], [Measures].[CONT_AMT_NET]} ON     COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
   FROM [SALES_ORDER]
  WHERE [~FILTER]
```

As of now I have hard coded the dates, that will come from parameters.
I am facing difficulty in creating the second set and how to do subtraction between two sets in MDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I totally agree with Sourav's answer as I think some form of aggregation will be needed; creating tuples with sets in them may raise an exception.

Here is a simple model, against AdvWrks, that is tested and will do a subtraction for you:

```
WITH 
  SET [Set1] AS 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20060301]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070308] 
  SET [Set2] AS 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070308]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080315]
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Set1Agg] AS 
     aggregate([Set1])
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Set2Agg] AS 
     aggregate([Set2])

  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x] AS 
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Set1Agg]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[y] AS 
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[All].[Set2Agg]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x-y] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x] - [Date].[Calendar].[All].[y] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[All].[y]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[All].[x-y]
  } ON 0
 ,[Product].[Category].[Category] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Reflecting against your code maybe something like the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [Set1] AS 
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-01]
    : 
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-30] 
  SET [Set2] AS 
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-03-01]
    : 
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-03-31] 
  MEMBER [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[Set1Agg] AS 
    Aggregate([Set1]) 
  MEMBER [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[Set2Agg] AS 
    Aggregate([Set2]) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[~Last30Days - Now] AS 
    (
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[Set1Agg]
     ,[Measures].[SomeMeasure]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[~Last60Days - Last30Days] AS 
    (
      [Created_Date.Created_Hir].[All].[Set2Agg]
     ,[Measures].[SomeMeasure]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[~Measure] AS 

        ([Measures].[~Last30Days - Now] - [Measures].[~Last60Days - Last30Days])
      / 
        [Measures].[~Last60Days - Last30Days]
    * 100 
   ,format_string = '#,##0' 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    {
      [Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].MEMBERS
    } 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS]
     ,[Measures].[CONT_AMT_NET]
     ,[Measures].[~Measure]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SALES_ORDER]
WHERE 
  [~FILTER];
```

Comment: Thanks @whytheq and Sourav For your help.
With your guidance now I am able to proceed. :)

Comment: Maybe it is a basic question but
Is it required to user .[ALL] or is there any alternative for this or what does it actually do , because whenever I am using it throws an error saying "calculated member cannot be used as a parent of another calculated member".

Comment: In that case, you can give my answer one shot too..it might work as it doesn't have a parent-child relationship.

Comment: (@SouravA I've upped it)

Answer (score 2):

You already have the logic on how to obtain sets of date corresponding to "last 30 days from now" and  "last 60 to last 30 days from now". So, I am going to skip that part.

NOTE - You would have to use the parameter values while building these sets.

What you want to do here is first find the values corresponding to these sets of dates and then perform operations on them.

You can proceed like this -

```
WITH
  SET [~FILTER] AS
    {[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-01]:[Created_Date.Created_Hir].[Created_On].[2014-04-30]}
  SET [~ROWS] AS
  {[Sales Order Attributes SO.Sales_order].[Sales Order ID].Members}
  SET [Last30Days] AS
  ... 
  SET [Last60ToLast30Days] AS
  ...
  MEMBER [~Last30Days - Now] AS
  Aggregate   
  (
      [Last30Days],
      [Measures].[SomeMeasure]
  )

  MEMBER [~Last60Days - Last30Days] AS
  Aggregate
  (
      [Last60ToLast30Days],
      [Measures].[SomeMeasure]
  )


  MEMBER [~Measure] AS
  ([~Last30Days - Now]-[~Last60Days - Last30Days] )/([~Last60Days - Last30Days] * 100), format_string = '#,##0'

  SELECT
   NON EMPTY {
                [Measures].[CONT_AMT_GROSS], 
                [Measures].[CONT_AMT_NET],
                [~Measure]
             } ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
   FROM [SALES_ORDER]
```

`Format_String` takes care of rounding.

Comment: did you create anything to test the above?

Comment: Something similar in my cube..do you foresee any issues?

Comment: Oops, I missed adding the aggregate. Thank you.